# AlTeRnAtE tHe CaSe

Tags: code-golf, string

For today's challenge, you must write a program or function that alternates the case of a string. However, you must ignore non-alphabetic characters. This means that every alphabetic character must have a different case than the preceding *and* following alphabetic character. This is slightly more complex than uppercasing every other letter for example. If you take a string such as

```
hello world
```

and convert every other character to uppercase, you'll get:

```
hElLo wOrLd
```

As you can see, the lowercase `o` is followed by a lowercase `w`. This is invalid. Instead, you must ignore the space, giving us this result:

```
hElLo WoRlD
```

All non-alphabetic characters must be left the same. The output can start with upper or lowercase, as long as it consistently alternates. This means the following would also be an acceptable output:

```
HeLlO wOrLd
```

Your program should work regardless of the case of the input.

The input string will only ever contain [printable ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), so you don't have to worry about unprintable characters, newlines or unicode. Your submission can be either a full program or a function, and you may take the input and output in any reasonable format. For example, function arguments/return value, STDIN/STDOUT, reading/writing a file, etc.

### Examples:

```
ASCII                                   ->  AsCiI
42                                      ->  42
#include <iostream>                     ->  #InClUdE <iOsTrEaM>
LEAVE_my_symbols#!#&^%_ALONE!!!         ->  lEaVe_My_SyMbOlS#!#&^%_aLoNe!!!
PPCG Rocks!!! For realz.                ->  PpCg RoCkS!!! fOr ReAlZ.
This example will start with lowercase  ->  tHiS eXaMpLe WiLl StArT wItH lOwErCaSe
This example will start with uppercase  ->  ThIs ExAmPlE wIlL sTaRt WiTh UpPeRcAsE
A1B2                                    ->  A1b2
```

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), standard loopholes apply and the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Ugh, I've only just realised this was *that* meme xD

Comment: @BetaDecay Hahaha, that was *not* my intention. More just unfortunate timing. I though of it [as a chat-mini-challenge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37648302#37648302), and I like the idea behind it because it's subtly harder than it seems.

Comment: The next challenge is to print an ascii spongebob à la `cowsay`

Comment: Darn it! I *just* wrote a CJam script for this (as in yesterday) and deleted it.

Comment: There is some missed potential for the title or at least the examples using either penguin of doom or sporks.

Comment: Random test cases: https://tio.run/##RY9BSwMxEIXPya8Ie0qwZEERpNKTLnqQFWzBQykSs1M3kk3CJEvtr1@Tbqs5zTzy3vcmHFPv3c00rZt207QPzZqt2O09e2nap81znu9ofmYIHhND5To/XDaTAJP3NlL6/vr2WIw@gONVPUasY68Q6s7oVB88drESEkF1XMgYrEnWOIhc0L1H9sGMK9lfwGesWFKCEEebcmZVUeLG4RMwL39MqY/aAp9d10JQontvNMTiYJX89sbxua@Magj576nk4nxZcRS2zjUL/uzOYGL2J1WaqGzoFRdLltVLoasV28aE0voD4IKVcQwBcLd18JP43FTseInIDAI2wpL9m4tOSUDjEp9VQek0/QI

Answer (score 22):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>66</s> 63 bytes

Starts with uppercase.

```js
s=>s.replace(/[a-z]/gi,c=>c[`to${(s=!s)?'Low':'Upp'}erCase`]())
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>s.replace(/[a-z]/gi,c=>c[`to${(s=!s)?'Low':'Upp'}erCase`]())

console.log(f("ASCII"))
console.log(f("42"))
console.log(f("#include <iostream>"))
console.log(f("LEAVE_my_symbols#!#&^%_ALONE!!!"))
console.log(f("PPCG Rocks!!! For realz."))
console.log(f("This example will start with lowercase"))
console.log(f("This example will start with uppercase"))
console.log(f("A1B2"))
```

Comment: Exactly how I was going to do it. I *think* I can see where you can save a couple of bytes but I'm on my phone so can't test properly.

Comment: Yup, using a ternary is what I was going to suggest.

Comment: How does the `s=!s` trick work?

Comment: That's a nice little trick :)

Comment: @KritixiLithos Because `s` is the input string, `!s` first evaluates to `false` (unless the input string is empty, in which case it _would_ evaluate to `true` -- but an empty string will not generate any match anyway). After that, it just becomes a standard boolean operation, alternating between `false` and `true`. Also, we don't mind losing the content of `s` at this point because it was already used to feed `.replace()`.

Comment: -1 byte if you use `[A-z]`, and remove the `i` flag

Comment: @MayorMonty Unfortunately, that would match a few symbols. An input such as `"A[I"` would fail.

Comment: So basically, it replaces every alphabetical character by looping through and getting the variable at index of a string, where the string is determined by alternating a boolean to get the lowercase or uppercase function names, then once it has the function then it calls it.

Answer (score 13):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 8 bytes

#### Code:

```
lvyJ¤aiš
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@59TVul1aEli5tGF///7uDqGucbnVsYXV@Ym5ecUKysqq8Wpxjv6@Pu5KioqAgA)

#### Explanation:

```
l           # Lowercase the input
 vy         # For each element..
   J        #   Join the entire stack into a single string
    ¤a      #   Check if the last character is alphabetic
      iš    #   If true, swapcase the entire string
```

Comment: I love how I try going in blind, knowing I have to beat 11-bytes; then slowly go from 17 to 11 bytes and realize `lvy¾Fš}Da½J` is exactly what you already had ._.

Comment: @carusocomputing There is a much easier 8 byte solution :p

Comment: oh, yeah, ***super*** easy haha.

Comment: How do we pronounce this language? Sable, perhaps?

Comment: @Octopus There is some discussion about this, but I use both 'osable' and 'osabie'.

Comment: @Octopus the github page says that its Base, from the github page: 'If the name 05AB1E was interpreted as a hexadecimal number and converted to base64, it would result into "Base" '

Comment: @Marnix, that explains its origin, not it's pronunciation.

Comment: @octopus I literally say `Oh-Five-Ay-Bee-One-Eee`, I am not a creative man.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I do the same, although it's `Zero-Five`, not `Oh-Five`. ;p

Answer (score 12):

## GNU Sed, 33

- 5 bytes saved thanks to @TobySpeight

Score includes +1 for `-r` flag to sed.

```
s/([a-z])([^a-z]*.?)/\U\1\L\2/gi
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#fYvRCoIwGEbv9xQbUlSgonQZhYlFICUV3WjJspGj2WT/xOrhWwZdd/WdA@cz4A5Sar@Ow0F6@u7ImQ3drMm8TGS@e@XGBLtwtUJjH1n8XojmwvCES9CK0WqK4ig4RHn1zOFZnaUAi1j9Uy8P4s06IoSgJAmXeCuLG3SGF1Lh7ideDtqXHDB70KoWDLdcCAyaKt2hLrGQLVMFBfY/a@r6lwXe3H/LWnN5B2OrDw).

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
nŒsTm2
ŒlŒuÇ¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@593dFJxSK4R19FJOUcnlR5uP7Ts/8PdWw63P2paE/n/v2Ows6cnl4kRl3JmXnJOaUqqgk1mfnFJUWpirh1XQICzu0JQfnJ2saKiooJbfpECUDynSo/Lx9UxzDU@tzK@uDI3KT@nWFlRWS1ONd7Rx9/PFaiUKyQjs1ghtSIxtyAnVaE8MydHobgksagEyCzJUCgtKEgtSk4sTgUA)

#### How it works

```
ŒlŒsÇ¦  Main link. Argument: s (string)

Œl      Cast to lowercase.
    Ç¦  At indices returned by the helper link...
  Œu        apply uppercase.


nŒsTm2      Helper link. Argument: s (string)

 Œs         Apply swapcase to s.
n           Perform vectorizing not-equal comparison.
   T        Compute the truthy indices.
    m2      Select every other one, starting with the first.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>86</s> <s>76</s> <s>68</s> <s>66</s> 63 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to DJMcMayhem</sup>
<sup>-3 bytes thanks to Cyoce</sup>

```python
x=0
for i in input():print(end=(2*i).title()[x]);x^=i.isalpha()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#DcJBCoAgEAXQfadwOdNComXhSaIg0PDDoGITeXvr8Xpz03DlamCQ/uVR4qVUJKWQvKN5BFuFSiDe2s5rOxws7lNKPIl7j0EkmzdX8R8) or [Try all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#hZBPa8JAEMXvfooJwe5ukVCkJ20KQaII0kotvYiGbbIhQzfZZWfF2C@fbmjvvQzz5/0evBkqVUPNSSwm0KcPE6iNAwTsgBbWYee56qqUz@9RJB69Vlwc@5NY9ucUEySpbSO5GEaKRurIssNqu2Uz9jgPJcau1JdKwRMa8k7J9jlsd3n2kRftraBb@2k0xVF8d54W2e71JY@iKCj2@9UG3kz5RWGGdXAPrP5Owum9QQLVy9ZqBVfUGshL50PrG9DmqlwpSf0nvFj7JzyF5OMDlr9xGRPDDw)

Comment: Two bytes shorter in python 3: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#DcJBCoAgEADAe6/w5m6ERMfCl0SBoOHComIb@XtrmN7sPFy5KlKU/uURwLVUSgKwjIRGSDgA7u2YQvJWa9zaacnQ7bhEB9i7joE5qzdX9voD "Python 3 – TIO Nexus")

Comment: any reason you can't do `print(end=(2*i).title()[x])`?

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
r"%l"_m"uv"gT°
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@1@kpJqjFJ@rVFqmlB5yaMP//0qOwc6enkoA)

#### Explanation

```
r              // RegEx replace input
 "%l"          // [A-Za-z] as first arg to replace
     _         // created function Z=>Z as second arg to replace
       "uv"gT° // alternates "u" & "v"
      m        // map Z to either "u" upper or "v" lower
```

Comment: Very nice! You can remove the `,`. Unless it's a number (i.e. `[12]`), Japt knows they're different items. I believe you can remove the `&1` as well.

Comment: Thanks @obarakon. The Japt documentation is a little sparse.

Comment: Thanks for using Japt. Feel free to ask questions, suggestions, etc. in the [Japt chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34018/japt). There's also a [Tips for Japt thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121253/61613). :)

Comment: `_m"uv"gT°` Nice. I was just about to suggest that.

Comment: @obarakon Yeah I saw where ETH responded to your question in the chat and it got me trying things out.

Comment: [You can save 2 bytes using Japt v2](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=clxsX20idXYiZ1Sw&input=IkExQjIi)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), <s>60</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

Thanks to DigitalTrauma for noticing bit 5 is the only difference for ASCII upper/lower case.

Special thanks to zch for golfing off three more bytes.

Save one more byte from RJHunter's idea

```c
l;f(char*s){for(;*s=isalpha(*s)?*s&95|++l%2<<5:*s;s++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-tcc#bU5da8IwFH3vr0gtSpKywWQ@bKmOTrohyBQHPlqy2NKym0ZylaGuP9vnWn0RIffhwD1fnAZETlUhLUd2zI2lguOwRAmbQtKWe@PYexn8hyF0@1E0eOUoMAyZqBsty4oy7@iR9i4NhBMtrt8VcqqHnSIDMOTPWFh3mNjstkg1Ezc9/h5PJk7lue@kg7JSsFtnJCoNbm0m9cjpmybxMkn1PsW9/jGAgR/0Vt00ns6@Et/3nZn5fPxJFkb9YusgH8aSth8Oj@7lT@93C2uvOVXmQUlVZGc)

Comment: I [golfed it a bit more](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#fY9RS8MwEMff9ynSFUuSorDp07I56qgyGDoUfLTEtKXFS1NyKzLn/NZ77mLfRMg93HH/@90d/x5ESVUlLUd2KI2lguOiRgltJanTlhDH0WTJ8ft6OuMY/QxFYBwzcey1rBvKRocRcfF7hXCixdANqaR6gTubdy0dVwWAIZ/GQj5mTLTdDqlm4h@XvKzWay9xM/WOw7pR0OUFmdfGaYXUt15@kyavaab3Ge71uwEMgzB6u8iSzdNjGgSBd3e7XT2QZ6M@0JHk3lji/sHXld/h5O6vg2N/asylkqoqzg), and modified so it works on all of gcc, tcc, clang.  FWIW, gcc puts string literals in read-only memory, so I used `strdup()` to get pointers to read-write memory in the test-driver code.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma thanks for that.  I should have recognized bit 5 was the difference between upper and lower.  Nice !

Comment: I [tried](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#fY9NS8NAEIbv/RWbBsPuBsVUT11riCVKoWhpwaNh3SQkOJsNmQaptf5rz3HNTYSdw3w@M8M7gCipqmTHkR0px0WNEtpK2pTFEIZBFHP8vJrNOQZfY2BxSTGM2PxSnAYt64ayyXFCrP2eIZxoMVajK6le4L7L@5ZOqwLAkHfTQT5lTLT9Hqlm4h@X7JarlZO4njnHft0o6POC3NTG9gqpb538Ok2e00wfMjzoVwPoe37wcpYl66fH1PM85@5ms3wgW6Pe0JLk3nTE/oOPC7fC6O6vgtPw3ZhzJVVV/AA) to make this version recursive too, but couldn't get it any shorter.

Comment: You can replace inner conditional with `*s&~32|++l%2<<5` to save 3 bytes.

Comment: Since the input promises to be printable ASCII, you can replace `&~33` with `&95` to save a further byte.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>57</s> <s>55</s> <s>47</s> 41 bytes

Byte count includes two bytes for command line options.
Run it for example like this: `$ ruby -p0 alternate_case.rb <<< "some input"`

```ruby
gsub(/\p{L}/){($&.ord&95|32*$.^=1).chr}
```

With the `p0` option, the entire input is consumed in one go, and the magical global `$.` is incremented to 1. This is later toggled between 0 and 1 and used for keeping the state.

Works with multiline input;
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#fYtPC4IwHEDv@xQTTSzIyuoQVGBhEUhJRadITEeOphv7TfrrV888dO72HrxXXaA4W52jePllp/myDNPmMjFHw3ffaRn2adJr2nEqy6pyd/PVCg0cpNM8ZkVC8JhyUJJE2RT5nnvwwuwRwiM7cwa6ppunRuj6m7WnaRoKgvkSb3l8hdrwgktcf@xpo31KAZN7lAlG8I0yhkFFUtWoUsz4jcg4AvI/K4T4ZW5v5ny4UJTnULVF9ws)

Thanks to Ventero for amazing input -- check the comments for details.

Comment: Man, if it weren't for the fact that `$.` auto-increments with each `gets` call, a full program with the `-p` flag would've been shorter...

Comment: @ValueInk Hah didn't even think of using the `-p` switch, but yeah, that one's hard to get around if had to make it work for multiline inputs (which I think you should in this case). You *could* add the line `$.+=1` on top to make it work, but then you're up to 56 bytes excluding the `-p` flag. And `BEFORE{i=0}` is way too long. Why isn't there another global integer? :D

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that you definitely need to work with multiple inputs with that solution in order to save space. Thankfully the `-p` flag usually counts as 1 byte by consensus, because `ruby -pe 'your code'` has an edit distance of 1 from `ruby -e 'your code'` so it is a tie with your solution at best.

Comment: `1&$.+=1` allows you to drop the parentheses. And for completeness' sake, there is another global integer - it's unfortunately just read-only: `$$`.

Comment: Another thing about the command line flag: `-p0` makes the interpreter read all available input in one go - so your code is only invoked once, allowing you to freely use `$.`. Combining that with the fact that `gsub` implicitly operates as `$_.gsub!` when specifying `-p` makes a full program significantly shorter: 48 characters for `gsub(/[a-z]/i){[$&.upcase,$&.downcase][1&$.+=1]}` and 2 for the `p0` flag.

Comment: Final remark, I promise :) Once you're using `-p0`, you can actually save a few more characters in how you flip `$.` back and forth: Since it's now guaranteed to be `1` when your code is invoked, you can simply use `$.^=1`.

Comment: Turns out I lied, I have another comment :D As the input is guaranteed to only ever contain printable ASCII, we can use Ruby's support for Unicode categories in regular expressions: `/\p{L}/` (Unicode category _Letter_) is one character shorter than `/[a-z|/i`.

Comment: @Ventero Hey, I got another Idea. Doesn't quite work yet -- Work in progress (*really* got to go to bed now): `gsub(/\p{L}/){($&.ord&~(32*($.^=1))).chr}` .. Too tired to see where the error is

Comment: instead of the `BEFORE{i=0}` thing you mentioned in a previous comment, you could do `i||=0`

Comment: @daniero I'm sure you'll spot it when you're fresher, but the AND-NOT technique only works to unset the lowercase bit (upcase); you'd need OR to set the lowercase bit on an uppercase letter (so it can cover downcase). Switching between Boolean operators could be done cleverly but probably no shorter than switching between string methods.

Comment: @daniero: You first need to clear out bit 5 before toggling it with `32*$.` to alternate between upper and lower case. After fiddling a bit with operator precedence, I think the shortest you can get with that approach is 42: `gsub(/\p{L}/){($&.ord&~32|32*$.^=1).chr}`. Unfortunately, `Integer` only has a `[]` method without corresponding `[]=`, otherwise you could just set the bit directly ...

Comment: @Ventero Since the challenge limits input to ASCII, `&95` should be safely equivalent to `&~32` to clear the lowercase bit.

Answer (score 5):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 18 bytes

```
/olZlYuN
@iy.u..//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@fnxOVE1nqx@WQWalXqqenr///v0dqTk6@Qnl@UU6KIgA)

#### Explanation

This program follows a lesser-known template for odd-length programs that run entirely in ordinal mode.  The linearized version of this code is:

```
il.l.uN.YuZyo@
```

Explanation of code:

```
i - push input onto stack            ["Hello world!"]
l - convert to lowercase             ["hello world!"]
. - duplicate                        ["hello world!", "hello world!"]
l - convert to lowercase (should be no-op, but avoids what seems to be a bug in the TIO implementation)
. - duplicate again                  ["hello world!", "hello world!", "hello world!"]
u - convert to uppercase             ["hello world!", "hello world!", "HELLO WORLD!"]
N - difference between sets          ["hello world!", "helloworld"]
. - duplicate reduced string         ["hello world!", "helloworld", "helloworld"]
Y - unzip (extract even positions)   ["hello world!", "helloworld", "hlool", "elwrd"]
u - convert to uppercase             ["hello world!", "helloworld", "hlool", "ELWRD"]
Z - zip evens back into string       ["hello world!", "helloworld", "hElLoWoRlD"]
y - perform substitution             ["hElLo WoRlD!"]
o - output                           []
@ - terminate
```

Without using `l` on the duplicate, the stack after `N` would be `["helloworld", "helloworld"]`.  I strongly suspect this is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
Xktkyy-f2L))5M(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x@RXZJdWambZuSjqWnqq/H/v3pGak5OvkJ5flFOijoA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#hYtNC4IwHMbvfYr/kFoeCpK6RWBmIdgLJdEpW7ZwuDXZJra@vO3UtcvD8/J7bt2lMpW1o2eQ@v5sO@xWWYfDU5QkuIengROPvQrePCjMmdRGUSIWrk3j8Bznwubairvk2kPe4NrPw3S/ixFCjjgcog0cZVFpl2EtFbgv/4zdlJVMA30TUXMKLeMctCHKOGtK4LKlqiCa/gObuv6B4WQZ4C8).

#### Explanation

Consider input 'hello world'

```
Xk    % To upper case
      % STACK: 'HELLO WORLD'
t     % Duplicate top element
      % STACK: 'HELLO WORLD', 'HELLO WORLD'
k     % To lower case
      % STACK: 'HELLO WORLD', 'hello word'
yy    % Duplicate top two elements
      % STACK: 'HELLO WORLD', 'hello word', 'HELLO WORLD', 'hello word'
-     % Difference (of code points; element-wise)
      % STACK: 'HELLO WORLD', 'hello word', [-32 -32 -32 -32 -32 0 -32 -32 -32 -32 -32]
f     % Indices of nonzeros
      % STACK: 'HELLO WORLD', 'hello word', [1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 11]
2L)   % Keep only even-indexed values (*)
      % STACK: 'HELLO WORLD', 'hello word', [2 4 7 9 11]
)     % Reference indexing (get values at indices)
      % STACK: 'HELLO WORLD', 'elwrd'
5M    % Push (*) again
      % STACK: 'HELLO WORLD', 'elwrd', [2 4 7 9 11]
(     % Assignment indexing (write values at indices). Implicit display
      % STACK: 'HeLlO wOrLd
```

'

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, 99 bytes

```
a->{String r="";int i=0;for(int c:a)r+=(char)(c>64&c<91|c>96&c<123?i++%2<1?c|32:c&~32:c);return r;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#lZFRT8IwFIXf@RV3I5AtxMUNQoJjI5OgIUEkYnwxSkop0ti1pO3ECfOvY4c86sNebk5ve79z2mKGlII7RPm@BkC5JnKNMIFpuQSYa0n5G2AHb5B8fgHkhqZf1ExRGmmKYQocIjiii3h/Piwj2w4NCWh0Ga6FdEqNr5ArW9GJ4zo47naauN/zDzjudY3yg/aAtlqNoO8P8KEdXOHmd1ndUBKdSQ4yLI5habvNlszYnt0/BF1BatI7v@aniOfoudIk9USmva3Z0ow73MOOncyH47HtaTE0URIpUe647ula/890gooDdcoxy1YE@lQoLQlK44qEySh5Gi3SfKHydCmYqlv15mtjkUzupyPLsirSZrPhLTwI/K7MLNwICSYT@/IqYh43VAH5ROmWEdhRxsp/kNpIvQEmdkRipEhFaOJf//28Ra04/gA)

```
a->{                          // Lambda with char-array parameter and String return-type
  String r="";                //  Result-String
  int i=0;                    //  Flag for alteration
  for(int c:a)                //  Loop over the characters of the input
    r+=(char)                 //   And append the result-String with the following (converted to char):
      (c>64&c<91|c>96&c<123?  //    If it's a letter:
       i++%2<1?               //     And the flag states it should be lowercase:
        (c|32)                //      Convert it to lowercase
       :                      //     Else (should be uppercase):
        (c&~32)               //      Convert it to uppercase
      :                       //    Else:
       c);                    //     Simply append the non-letter character as is
                              //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return r;                   //  Return result-String
}                             // End of method
```

Comment: I couldn't get it shorter but you might be able to use `(c+"").matches("[A-Za-z]")` or `Character.isLetter(c)` to save bytes.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Both are longer than `c>64&c<91|c>96&c<123` though. And since the I use `int` anyway for the `Character.toUpperCase(...)` and `Character.toLowerCase(...)` golfed parts (these: `(char)(c&~32)` and `(char)(c|32)`), I doubt I could make it shorter with either of those.

Comment: I thought you wouldn't be able to but worth posting to see if you could make use of them anyway

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Ah ok. :) In some cases the first might help with a slightly different approach for other challenges, but for this challenge it's shorter as is. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `a->{String r="";int i=0,f=32;for(int c:a)r+=(char)(c>64&c<91|c>96&c<123?(f=~f):c);return r;}
`??

Comment: @RomanGräf Umm.. but where does it use `c` in the `(f=~f)` part? Currently [it doesn't really work..](https://tinyurl.com/y8qz56ww)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 25 bytes

```
{ḷ|ụ}ᵐ.{ḷ∈Ạ&}ˢ¬{s₂{∈Ạ}ᵐ}∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@1/9cMf2moe7l9Y@3DpBD8R51NHxcNcCtdrTiw6tqS5@1NRUDREBKah91LH8/3@ljNScnHyF8vyinBSl/1EA)

This is both long and slow.

#### Explanation

```
{   }ᵐ.                       The Output is the result of mapping on each char of the Input:
 ḷ                              Lowecase the char
  |                             Or
   ụ                            Uppercase the char
       {    }ˢ                In the Ouput, select the chars that:
        ḷ∈Ạ&                    when lowercased are in "abc...xyz" (ie are letters)
              ¬{       }∧     In that new string, it is impossible to find:
                s₂              a substring of 2 consecutive chars
                  {∈Ạ}ᵐ         where both of them are in the lowercase alphabet
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
srR~xZ}dGrZ
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=srR~xZ%7DdGrZ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%27ASCII%27%0A%2742%27%0A%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%27%0A%27LEAVE_my_symbols%23%21%23%26%5E%25_ALONE%21%21%21%27%0A%27PPCG+Rocks%21%21%21+For+realz.%27%0A%27This+example+will+start+with+lowercase%27%0A%27This+example+will+start+with+uppercase%27%0A%27A1B2%27&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
              # Z = 0; Q = eval(input())
srR~xZ}dGrZQ  # Auto-fill variables
         rZQ  # lowercase the input
 rR           # Apply the r function to each letter of the input with
   ~xZ}dG     # ... this as the other argument
   ~          # use the old value of the variable Z, then update it with the value of ...
    xZ        # Z xor ...
      }dG     # the variable d is a lowercase letter
              # because of how mapping works in pyth, d will contain the current letter
              # This causes Z to flip between 0 and 1, alternately upper and lower casing
              # the current character if it is a letter
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>32</s>  30 bytes

```perl6
{S:g/<:L><-:L>*<:L>?/$/.tclc()/}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#jZFdS8MwFIbv8yvOmLpOtxaHeLGPalaqFKorW6dMhqNmcQumbWjSfSj@Mu/8YzMdKgiKOxfhnJznPTm8ySWFxalJWihewwFJpxQ6m5dBc2a1m77druvjsMjOrD3LVIQTo2q9bjR7rqhU0AHOEiqN6vubKQVnyqjU7UpRqYzFLZTr8aEGW0jwKIGjraqFHtPsc0DdBmPMEpGrGozpSlCi6LQKLwiASSj2Mbbdag2@ujXY3piCZhy9bvDA8Tz4P/RLgKXDPHTSgJ2iUJw0UJklhOfamDZLpcpoFNt/4mUvcfhw6mq2J8PMja5s5Lv4xp3E64lcxw8pl@VS@eB@f4L93rVbKpV@6H2KF5odTeQo7qb@N8t7ScGiIHAuoZ@SJ1koL7SNeh/@bP62SyCcmWadp0HBPvYy6FPM70wUzrW1dBXFglNYMs5BqihTOlVzyIX2lUT637ZDwrknwV3hOOAuLD3ugwyjvoJbFs5hKALaJ1i6CB93G7taio8fGh8)

```perl6
{S:g{<:L><-:L>*<:L>?}=$/.tclc}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#jZHfSsMwFMbv8xRnTF2nW8UhXritmpUqhepKV5XJcNQsurC0DU26P449mXe@2EyLCoKi5yKck/P7Tg5fcklhfmKSNopXsEfSCYXudj04fV53Tj2r09THfpGdbbo7h6YinGy2mjxXVCroAmcJlUb97dWUgjNl1JpWrahUxuI2yvXwUINtJHiUwEGpaqOnNPsY0LTAGLFE5KoBI7oUlCg6qcMaATAJxTZG2a034LPbgPLGFDTjaLPFA9t14e/QLwGWNnPRcQv@FYXiuIWqLCE817Z0WCpVRqPY@hWvuonNbyaOZvsyzJzoykKeg2@dcbway1X8mHJZrVT3HnbH2OtfO5VK5Zveo3iu2eFYDuNe6n2xvJ8ULPJ9@xKClMxkobzQNup9@Iv50y6@sJ81a88GBfvUzyCgmN@bKJxqa@kyigWnsGCcg1RRpnSqppAL7SuJ9L@VQ8KpK8FZ4tjnDixc7oEMo0DBHQuncCN8GhAsHYSPeq3/WoqPHlvv)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  S            # string replace (not in-place) implicitly against ｢$_｣

  :global

  {

    <+ :L >    # a letter
    <- :L >*   # any number of non-letters
    <+ :L >?   # an optional letter

  }

  =

  $/.tclc()    # uppercase the first letter, lowercase everything else
}
```

Comment: Pity you can't use `.=` in substitution regexes, otherwise you could do `.=tclc`

Answer (score 3):

## q/kdb+, <s>51</s> <s>42</s> 38 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{@[x;;upper]1#'2 cut(&)x in .Q.a}lower
```

**Example:**

```
q){@[x;;upper]1#'2 cut(&)x in .Q.a}lower"hello world"
"HeLlO wOrLd"
```

**Notes:**

```
.Q.a        // abcde...xyz lowercase alphabet
(&) x in    // where, returns indices for where x (hello world) is an alpha
2 cut       // splits list into 2-item lists
1#'         // takes first item of each 2-item list; ie the indices to uppercase
@[x;;upper] // apply (@) upper to x at these indices
```

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, 264 bytes

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN("",IF(REGEXMATCH(MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(A1))),1),"[A-Za-z]"),CHAR(CODE(UPPER(MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(A1))),1)))+MOD(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(LEFT(A1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(A1)))),"[^A-Za-z]","")),2)*32),MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(A1))),1))))
```

It's a big mess but it's a little easier if you expand it out:

```
=ArrayFormula(
  JOIN(
    "",
    IF(REGEXMATCH(MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(A1))),1),"[A-Za-z]"),
      CHAR(
        CODE(UPPER(MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(A1))),1)))
        +
        MOD(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(LEFT(A1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(A1)))),"[^A-Za-z]","")),2)*32
      ),
      MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(A1))),1)
    )
  )
)
```

The pseudo-logic would run like this:

```
For each character {                                    // ArrayFormula()
  If (character is a letter) {                          // REGEXMATCH(MID())
    Return CHAR(                                        // CHAR()
      CODE(UPPER(letter))                               // CODE(UPPER(MID()))
      +
      If (nth letter found and n is odd) {32} else {0}  // MOD(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(LEFT())))
    )
  } else {
    Return character                                    // MID()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>17</s>, 13 bytes

```
VUÍáƒ¨áü$©/ì&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#ATcAyP//VlXDjcOhwoPCqMOhw7wkwqkvw6wm//9MRUFWRV9teV9zeW1ib2xzIyEjJl4lX0FMT05FISEh)

Or [Verify all test cases!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@x/mHnq49/DCQ82HVhxeeHiPyqGV@ofXqP3/7xjs7OnJZWLEpZyZl5xTmpKqYJOZX1xSlJqYa8fl4@oY5hqfWxlfXJmblJ9TrKyorBanGu/o4@/nqqioyBUQ4OyuEJSfnF0M5Cm45RcpAPXlVOlxhWRkFiukViTmFuSkKpRn5uQoFJckFpUAmSUZCjn55alFyYnFqfiVlRYUQJU5GjoZAQA)

HeXdUmP:

```
00000000: 5655 cde1 83a8 e1fc 24a9 2fec 26         VU......$./.&
```

Explanation:

This uses a *compressed regex*™️, so before explaining it, let's expand the regex out:

```
:%s/\v\a.{-}(\a|$)/\l&
```

The `VU` converts everything to uppercase. Then we run this:

```
:%                      " On every line:
  s/\v                  "   Substitute:
      \a                "     A letter
        .{-}            "     Followed by as few characters as possible
            (\a|$)      "     Followed by either another letter or an EOL
                  /     "   With:
                   \l   "     The next character is lowercased
                     &  "     The whole text we matched
```

---

Old/more interesting answer:

```
:se nows
Vuò~h2/á
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
qeu{_'[,65>&,T^:T{el}&}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@YWlodrx6tY2Zqp6YTEmcVUp2aU6tWq/r/f0hGZrFCakVibkFOqkJ5Zk6OQnFJYlEJkFmSoZCTX55alJxYnAoA)

#### Explanation

```
q         e# Read all input.
eu        e# Uppercase it.
{         e# For each character:
 _        e#  Duplicate it.
 '[,65>&  e#  Set intersection with the uppercase alphabet.
 ,        e#  Length (either 0 or 1 in this case).
 T^:T     e#  XOR with T (T is initially 0), then store the result back in T.
 {el}&    e#  If The result of the XOR is true, lowercase the character.
}%        e# (end for)
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 71 Bytes

```php
for(;a&$c=$argn[$i++];)echo ctype_alpha($c)?(ul[$k++&1].cfirst)($c):$c;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVfJIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVFUsv6fll@kYZ2oppJsC1YQrZKprR1rrZmanJGvkFxSWZAan5hTkJGooZKsaa9RmhOtkq2trWYYq5eclllUXKIJErdSSbb@/x8A)

Answer (score 2):

**C 64 bytes**

```
B;R(char *s){for(;*s=isalpha(*s)?(B=!B)?*s|=32:*s&=~32:*s;s++);}
```

Takes advantage of ascii encoding where upper and lower case letters are offset by 0x20.

Comment: You don't need the ' ' space between `char` and `*s`

Comment: This looks *very* similar to @cleblanc's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122798/11259).

Comment: I posted it when  @cleblanc's post used toUpper() and toLower().

Comment: [My comment suggesting this approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122783/alternate-the-case/122798#comment301120_122798) was at 18:29:34Z.  [cleblanc's edit to incorporate this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/122798/revisions) was at 18:37:36Z.  Your answer was posted at 18:38:21Z.  So I guess cleblanc's answer was less than a minute before your post.  Your answer is remarkably similar to my suggestion, but I guess that's the nature of code-golf - often solutions in the same language will converge to the same thing - so I'll let it slide :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 32 bytes

```
T`l`L
01T`L`l`[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#fYtBC4IwAEbv@xUbUoegSOkYxRILYZSUdEhSlw0cbU22idWftxWdu3y8D97r01KUBEz9tCSOMjw@nbP8s6MvL/seH8I4BrMAePxeifbK4JwrYzWjcgFIhI9RIZ@FecqLEsZD3jAfFJjsthFCCCRJuIF7Vd2Me3CtNHSdeE1AWnMD2YPKRjDYcSGgsVRbh7aGQnVMV9Sw/1rbND8N@6vgDQ)

First converts the input to uppercase, and then groups the input into matches containing up to two capital letters. The only time it will contain only one letter is if the last letter doesn't have a pair. Then it lowercases the first letter of each of these matches.

The `01` in the second stage translates roughly to: do not change the behaviour of this stage based on the match number, but only apply the changes to the first character of each match.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 86 bytes

```ps
-join($args[0]|%{if($_-match"[a-z]"-and($i=!$i)){"$_".toupper()}else{"$_".tolower()}})
```

Input is a `[char[]]` array.

#### Comments in code for explanation

```ps
# Join the array of string and char back together.
-join
    # Take the first argument and pass each element ([char]) down the pipe. 
    ($args[0]|%{
        # Check if this is a letter. Second condition is a boolean that changes at every pass 
        # but only if the current element is a letter. If not the condition never fires
        if($_-match"[a-z]"-and($i=!$i)){
            # Change the character to uppercase
            "$_".toupper()
        }else{
            # Output the character to lowercase. 
            # Special characters are not affected by this method
            "$_".tolower()
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>105</s> 83 + <s>2</s> 4 + 1 byte of separator = <s>108</s> <s>86</s> 88 Bytes

```
import Data.Char
f#(x:y)|isLetter x=([toUpper,toLower]!!f)x:(1-f)#y|1>0=x:f#y
_#l=l
```

Function is `(1#)`, starts lowercase. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#bYqxCoMwFAB3vyKaDgptaaRTaARrF8FNOpVSgiY0oCY8nzSC/26XDh288e5W0zsLSG4S5bF4Swg0jT2fk8WMlUJUQLyIH2jvzinYo63sR8EzDHXiecwOOqHzwrKT8FzTOXjRTnRrL80gWkvchDVCNewYjfK6KMsoID/@0znd9tQMTTe1ilyMHRGU7LPtMWfXNFq/)

<s>The sad thing is that this is longer than the Java and C# answers</s> Thanks to Ørjan Johansen for saving 22 bytes by merging three lines into one!

Comment: I saw it needed those long imported functions so I didn't even try... but that's a bit much, you can merge some lines: `f#(x:y)|isLetter x=([toUpper,toLower]!!f)x:(1-f)#y|1>0=x:f#y`

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but I think `1#` does not count as an anonymous function. In my understanding, one should be able to bind an anonymous function to an identifier, but e.g. `f=1#` won't work. Instead you need the section `(1#)` for +2 bytes. This is also implicitly stated in our [community guidelines for golfing in Haskell](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11935/56433), though maybe those should be adapted to explicitly mention this case.

Comment: @Laikoni ok, answer updated

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 24 bytes

**23 bytes + 1 byte for `-p`.**

Thanks to [@Dada](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55508/dada) for -2 bytes.

```perl
s/\pl/--$|?uc$&:lc$&/eg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYvNCoJAFEb3PsWI1s6soE2/mFgIUlLRKhKzIYeuzjB3xAyfvclF6zYf58D5BJUw0Xa7GM40uhcBruPY7arK7P4UunHpQ2vv6IehYbEyg@pOyZxxVJKmxdKIAu8cJEWTYFPcOKBlWv1rL/Gi/S4wTdOIY39LDjx7YmdkwyXpfvAeGKecIaGvtBBASc0ACKpUqg5VToDXVGYp0v9ZJcQv80br8YcLxXiJ2hFf)

Comment: Neat. `\pl` instead of `[a-z]` to 2 bytes tho :)

Comment: @Dada, I genuinely didn't know that! How didn't I know that!! Thank you!

Comment: I think I learned it from Ton Hospel, and I use it now and then (actually I tend to forget about it too often and use `[a-z]` instead!). If you wonder, it comes from [perlrecharclass](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 17 bytes

```perl
s/\pL/<`>|uc$&/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYtBC4IwGIbv@xXfWHkrSeomgomFICUVnSKzNVLa2tgmZvTfbYfOnd7ngedVTPPFQLByCxM1GP@kcj@8RJ@Wjjz/zoYh3idZhuYBIs2T8vbGIGyksZpVIkJ5Gh/TUvSl6cVVckMw8c7jMs63mxRjjIoiWcNO0odxBiupwf34e4oOdWOAvSqhOIOu4RyMrbR1aGvgsmOaVob9z1qlflk8WwbwBQ)

Comment: What's the magic thing that's happening here to alternate it... I'm not seeing it obviously. I'm sure I've seen this elsewhere (possibly you too!) but I can't guess what's causing it...

Comment: @DomHastings ``<`>`` is a [glob expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) - in scalar context it yields a backtick then undef alternating

Comment: That makes sense to me, but it's how the substitution tracks that through each replacement that confuses me - since you're only replacing one letter at a time... I guess it's probably me not understanding how the substitution works on a deeper level perhaps?

Comment: @DomHastings It's a bit weird but each glob has global state. Maybe see this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZFfS8MwFMXf8yluV7QKpVuHvrg5qGPKYOhQ8dFxG@/WsLQpSeo6Rb96zf4w8UHBPIR7k/s7nJOUpOV5UxmCOaGtNIHBda/xYSFVChmabYESjEVLrNSisGA4StTbm5PgHcM05B/BadgKWzBXGuIoijs9thFiPqA0CqRYEthMmJ8KfYQU@OA/ZFAfVnD5adpRey8SOZG2psUBL5T9pi/cTkCvLsmCCtIujIG4A1yVwlVqvgtMyDNYCZuBsO50Vexzb8DgN@u9oI47TZM8DMdjdtZlvii4rF4I@kIZqwnzAZuMkqfRLF/PzDpPlTS@5x8/H82Syd3tyPM8Np0Ob@Be8aVxHVy7t3CcfIvYozMPVGNeSnLO5PYntN2ZlGpFmqOhv8eqstyPJfFVF74A "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: That's really useful. Ok thanks for that! I had no idea and I don't know how that's tracked internally, A quick search doesn't yield any Perl monks discussion but super useful to know... [Might warrant a tip?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5105/9365) Thanks for explaining what you know here though!

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 46 bytes

```
T`L`l
T`l`L`.(?=([^a-z]*|[a-z][^a-z]*[a-z])*$)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#fYvNCoJAGEX38xQzWJFCQtKyH0wsBCkpaSOpkw049NmIo5jSu5uF61bnHji382M3BuTH0FOfblbTIKSz9qq9gy8G@W1VG6ldZ54tx0ELAyn8mUB1Z3jJhSwLRrM1cm3zYkdZE8kmuwmQClEm4Tgy3ePBJoQgz7P2@CSSh@wN70SB@x@0OvJTLjF70SwHhmsOgGVJi7KfZYpB1KxIqGT/syrPh8ycb40P) Includes test cases.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 5, 54 bytes

```
<?=preg_filter('/\pL/e','($0|" ")^a^aA[$i^=1]',$argn);
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 100 bytes

```c#
s=>{var r="";int m=0;foreach(var c in s)r+=char.IsLetter(c)?(char)(++m%2>0?c|32:c&~32):c;return r;};
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 192 bytes

```
x=list(input())
s=[]
for i in x[1::2]:
 s.append(i)
 x.remove(i)
s.reverse()
while len(x)<len(s):
 x.append("")
while len(x)>len(s):
 s.append("")
for i in range(len(x)):
 print(end=x[i]+s[i])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#ZZDNDoIwDMfvPkXDqYsJiR6J@CKEA0qBJliWFXBvj5OBidrD@pHfv1271NSAmwRNdoBgPu9ZR2Sx04jGrDXNi3INmsEBAwv44pRl5zJKQNPKWpIaOfLgU0ePYaa9oCGfySlhzJ8d9wQ9CXpzeTvdpgfl1ipJ/tHrF6q/6Od3rpKWMGp22jqWEQOe@4LLo4bHLOveS3W7hyO0Hb8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 79 bytes

```
{x=0;it.toUpperCase().collect{(it==~/\w/)?x++%2?it:it.toLowerCase():it}.join()}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r\lÈgYguiv
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=clxsyGdZZ3Vpdg&input=ImhlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCEi)

Answer (score 1):

## *[Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!)*, 110 bytes

```
N*8
Count i while _/256 {
_+_/520*(727/_)*2+_/776*(983/_)*4
Write _/8+32*(_%4/3-_%8%5/4)
(_+(_%8+2)/4)%2+N*8
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc1BC4IwGMbx@z7FhizmRixep1tHCW9it7r14iRI0IQ0QqLPvubx9@eBp@0670NopCOn6f1caE8/j364U9SQF/RLUKHO4SCFBasxlRBtbSHF0WWbDbm@@mXbO5WBFMiNzvbIHc@1SYlAFZNTkEZxUNvRL4S6Ki8VjivO6@inYU5YsrtxLOtzUzHG/g)

#### Algorithm

```
Set toLower flag to 0
Read a character
While not EOL:
  Calculate isUpper and isLower flags
  If isUpper && toLower, output (character + 32)
  If isLower && !toLower, output (character - 32)
  Else, output character unchanged
  If isUpper or isLower, toggle toLower
  Reset isUpper and isLower, and read a new character
```

#### Accumulator partitioning

We reserve the lowest three bits of the accumulator for storing the flags: toLower in the 1's place, isUpper in the 2's place, and isLower in the 4's place. The rest of the accumulator, at the 8's place and above, stores the input character.

For example, with input of `Hello World`, after reading the `H` and calculating flags, the accumulator has a value of 578, or in binary:

```
1001000 0 1 0
   |    | | \-> toLower (false)
   |    | \---> isUpper (true)
   |    \-----> isLower (false)
   \----------> ASCII code for 'H'
```

After reading the space, the accumulator is 257:

```
0100000 0 0 1
   |    | | \-> toLower (true)
   |    | \---> isUpper (false)
   |    \-----> isLower (false)
   \----------> ASCII code for ' '
```

#### Code

**Line 1**

```
N*8
```

Stores the first input character and sets all the flags to 0.

**Line 2**

```
Count i while _/256 {
```

Loops while the accumulator value is >= 256 (i.e. the character's ASCII code is at least 32).

**Line 3**

```
_+_/520*(727/_)*2+_/776*(983/_)*4
```

Calculates the isUpper and isLower flags. The main trick here is using integer division for the inequalities. For example, if `x` is a printable-ASCII code, then `65 <= x` is equivalent to `x/65` with integer division: values smaller than 65 become 0, values between 65 and 126 become 1, and we don't have to worry about anything larger than 126. We can use this approach for all four inequalities (keeping in mind that the ASCII codes are all multiplied by 8 in the accumulator).

isUpper:

```
65 <= char <= 90
65*8 <= acc <= 90*8+7
acc/520 == 1 && 727/acc == 1

Expression: _/520*(727/_)
```

isLower:

```
97 <= char <= 122
97*8 <= acc <= 122*8+7
acc/776 == 1 && 983/acc == 1

Expression: _/776*(983/_)
```

This line, then, takes the accumulator and adds `isUpper*2 + isLower*4` to it.

**Line 4**

```
Write _/8+32*(_%4/3-_%8%5/4)
```

Outputs the character, swapping case if necessary.

There are two instances in which we need to modify the ASCII value before output:

1. isUpper is 1, toLower is 1

   - We need to convert the uppercase letter to lowercase by adding 32
   - The three flag bits are 011, i.e. acc%4 == 3
2. isLower is 1, toLower is 0

   - We need to convert the lowercase letter to uppercase by subtracting 32
   - The three flag bits are 100, i.e. acc%8 == 4

We can simulate the equality test using mod and int-div. For example, `acc%8 == 4` is equivalent to `acc%8%5/4`:

```
acc%8      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
     %5    0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2
       /4  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

This line, therefore, takes 1 if we need to convert upper-to-lower, subtracts 1 if we need to convert lower-to-upper, multiplies that by 32, adds it to the ASCII code, and outputs it.

**Line 5**

```
(_+(_%8+2)/4)%2+N*8
```

Toggle the toLower flag if necessary; inputs and stores a new character.

We need to toggle toLower if the character was a letter, i.e. either isUpper or isLower was set. The possible flag bit values are `010`, `011`, `100`, and `101`--i.e. 2 through 5 (note that 6 and 7 are not possible because a letter can't be both upper- and lowercase). This expression gives 1 for those values and 0 otherwise:

```
 _%8       0 1 2 3 4 5
    +2     2 3 4 5 6 7
(     )/4  0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Call this value isLetter. Then we want the new value of toLower to be `toLower XOR isLetter` (if isLetter is true, swap the value of toLower; otherwise, leave it unchanged). We can do XOR by adding the two values mod 2. Finally, we also read another character with `N`, multiply it by 8, and add it in.

Answer (score 1):

## [MUMPS](http://www.cs.uni.edu/%7Eokane/), 98 bytes

```
 f i=1:1:$l(s) s c=$e(s,i) s:c?1A u=c?1U,f=$s(f="":u,1:'f),$e(s,i)=$c(2*f-1*-'(f=u)*32+$a(c))
 w s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZJNT8MwDIbv@xXuB6wtGVIGp4qASlXQpAkmGBypQpaqEenHmkRl/PkSTdxA4WTL7@PXluXGNL2aYAdUaj60VPNtzXOqeORnz/lq5cczGMH7E7hcutRAtEyaHYcr0Sk9cNpcu/B1kb0WZXMo1aF576QKvOD07aTM1o8Phed5rtbNJr@Hp459KAvCXTeAnSa/zl09uhYK@CdteslhFFKC0nTQNtU1yG7kA7Ocy2HrcjB9/79Dhm@PF9zPfmnKllsQiCGDqgkqEASnOA2lVUABI6FlkLB5ym5wBobY8IIqEqqoIr6fGoTTeRWjH46ELFom1QIni7kFTJxcLM9CGrH4uJ/9gP30DQ)

- `f i=1:1:$l(s)`: Set `i=1` and loop over this line of code until `i` reaches the length of the input string `s` (inclusive). `i` is incremented by 1 each loop.
- `s c=$e(s,i)`: Assign the `i`th character of `s` to `c` using the `$extract` function.
- `s:c?1A`: Execute the following `set` statements if `c` is an alphabetical character (uppercase or lowercase). This line and the next use M's built-in string matching system.
- `u=c?1U`: Make `u` a boolean storing whether `c` is an uppercase character. There is only one data type in M so `u`'s value will be `1` for true or `0` for false.
- `f=$s(f="":u,1:'f)`: Make `f` a boolean storing whether `c` should be an uppercase character. `f`'s value will also be `1` or `0`. It's assigned `u` if this is the first alphabetic character because the first alphabetic character is in the right case by definition. Otherwise its value is flipped from its previous value using the `not` operator `'`.
- `$e(s,i)=$c(2*f-1*-'(f=u)*32+$a(c))`: The left-hand side is the `i`th character of `s` again; we're setting it equal to the right-hand side which modifies `s` itself.  `$a` (for `$ascii`) and `$c` (for `$char`) are inverses: the former converts characters to the corresponding ASCII number and the latter converts numbers back into characters. The argument of `$c` is a compact way to add 32 to `$a(c)` if `c` is lowercase but should be uppercase, subtract 32 from `$a(c)` if `c` is uppercase but should be lowercase, and add 0 if `c` is already in the right case. Note that M's operator precedence is strictly left to right, so `2*f-1*x` is unintuitively the same as `(2*f-1)*x`.
- Finally, `w s` prints the now-alternating `s`.

Both lines have a leading space so that their first characters are interpreted as commands and not labels.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 8 bytes

```
ʀTy?⇩⁽⇧V
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiIiwiyoBUeT/ih6nigb3ih6dWIiwiIiwiQTFCMiJd)

The `r` flag shouldn't be needed, but bugs, bugs, bugs.

Answer (score 0):

## [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 16 bytes

```
¯{_U&,R^:R{¬}&}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PK0ut@P//0Prq@FA1naA4q6DqQ2tq1WpV////X5JaXJKZlw4A)

Convex port of [@Business Cat's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122802/36670).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 95 bytes

Not nearly as golfed as @Rod's, but I'm posting it nevertheless.

```python
lambda s:"".join([s[i],[s[i].lower(),s[i].upper()][i%2]][s[i].isalpha()]for i in range(len(s)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvBCsIwEAV/ZVMQNlBy0JvgSdBr8RpziJra1bgJSYroz8e2Xh7MMC9@yhB4U/vduXr7utws5G3TqEcgRp01mXZZ5cPbJZTtAmOMMxhNq7Ux/4Cy9XGwk@1DAgJiSJbvDr1jzFLKGhNxwR6J41hwNl23P8IpXJ9ZCAGH6Zec9V/1Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 40 bytes

```
(2|+/\@:e.&Alpha_j_)`(tolower,:toupper)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NYxqtPVjHKxS9dQccwoyEuOz4jUTNEryc/LLU4t0rErySwsKUos0a/9rcqUmZ@QrqDsWO2d6qivoWimkATnBzp6e6lAZEyOYMJAFFVP2zHPOCU1xVbDJ9C8OKXJN9LWDKVLOzEvOKU1JBUrlF5cUpSbm2qn/BwA)

This follows almost directly from the definition of [Composite Item (`}`)](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/curlyrt):

We stack the upper and lowercase version of the input for our two possibilities using `(tolower,:toupper)`.

Next we create a boolean list to indicate whether each character is alphabetic: `e.&Alpha_j_` and take the scan sum of that: `+/\@:` which creates a monotonically increasing list which increases only on alphabetic characters.  Finally we turn *that* into a boolean list where evens are 0 and odds are 1: `2|`.

Putting those parts together means we alternate between the lower and uppercase versions of our input whenever we encounter a new alphabetic character, and only then.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 84 bytes

```cs
int m,c;for(;(c=Read())>0;)Write((char)(c>64&c<91|c>96&c<123?m++%2>0?c|32:c&~32:c));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/M69EIVcn2Totv0jDWiPZNig1MUVDU9POwFozvCizJFVDIzkjsUhTI9nOzEQt2cbSsCbZztIMyDI0MrbP1dZWNbIzsE@uMTaySlarA5Gamtb//yckJiVXVFZVKzg4OjlHREZFKwAFgDSIUgAKAQA)

Modified version of [The Lethal Coder's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122934/8340) that takes advantage of some of the features of the interactive compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, 104 bytes

I'm kind of new to this but wanted to submit anyway.

`x=>x.split('').forEach((s,i)=>x+=i%2?s.toUpperCase():s.toLowerCase())||x.substring(x.length/2,x.length);`

It takes in a string, splits it into an array so it can loop through with `forEach` and fit in as a one-liner, then goes through each character and index and adds the uppercase or lowercase version of the character depending on if the index is odd or not, then "or"s it with what I want to return (since otherwise it's undefined) and returns the second half of the string, so I don't have to clear the string to begin with or declare a new one.

However, this doesn't work with non-letter characters, so here's my pseudocode for something that would do that:

```
const sarcasticText = str=> {
    let newStr = '', numSkip = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        numSkip += str[i].match(/[a-z]/i) ? 0 : 1;
        newStr += (i + numSkip) % 2 ? str[i].toUpperCase() : str[i].toLowerCase();
    }
    return newStr;
};
```

Basically, I'd implement a counter to check how many characters to offset.

Answer (score 0):

## SM83, 29 bytes

Input pointer in `hl`, output in `de`, trashes `bc`, `a`, flags.

```
06 55 2A 4F CB AF D6 41
38 0C FE 1A 30 08 CB A9
CB 08 38 02 CB E9 79 12
13 B7 20 E6 C9
```

Disassembled:

```
fun:
    ld  b,$55       ;; 06 55    ; set b to alternating bits
loop:
    ld  a,(hl+)     ;; 2A       ; load char
    ld  c,a         ;; 4F       ; and into c
    res 5,a         ;; CB AF    ; turn a-z into A-Z
    sub 65          ;; D6 41    ; subtract 'A'
    jr  c,store     ;; 38 0C    ; if was less, not a letter
    cp  26          ;; FE 1A    ; compare to 26
    jr  nc,store    ;; 30 08    ; if not less, not a letter
    res 5,c         ;; CB A9    ; it is a letter; make uppercase
    rrc b           ;; CB 08    ; rotate b and check low bit
    jr  c,store     ;; 38 02    ; every other time skip next bit
    set 5,c         ;; CB E9    ; actually, make lowercase
store:
    ld  a,c         ;; 79       ; store faster this way
    ld  (de),a      ;; 12       ; store
    inc de          ;; 13       ; and increment
    or  a           ;; B7       ; quick test against 0
    jr nz,loop      ;; 20 E6    ; if not 0 continue
    ret             ;; C9       ; else return
```

Answer (score 0):

## brev, 103 bytes

```
(define h(make-parameter #f))(over(if(char-alphabetic? x)((if(h(not(h)))char-upcase char-downcase)x)x))
```

Are the examples wrong? How do you get to `InClUdE` from `AsCiI`?