# Is it a pleasing number?

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem

A pleasing number (according to this definition) is a number that can be passed through the following process (let's use `41802000` as an example):

- Separate the trailing identical numbers (`41802000 => [41802, 000]`)
- Sort the first half of the digits and take the maximum (`[41802, 000] => [8, 000]`)
- Take the length of the final element. Call the resultant elements *A* and *B* (`[8, 000] => A=8, B=3`)
- Is N<sup>B</sup> = A for any integer `N`? (`True` in this example; 2<sup>3</sup> = 8)

If the input results in `True` from the following process, it is considered pleasing.

Your task is to take an integer `x`, and output whether `x` is a pleasing number. You can output any two distinct values for truthy and falsey, but please state what you're using in your answer. `x` is guaranteed to have at least two distinct digits (e.g. `111` is an invalid input). As with most challenges, you may take `x` as a string, or a list of digits.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in *bytes* wins.

### Test cases

```
          Input          Output
       41802000               1
            100               1
      123456788               0
      451111111               0
234543454545444               0
             12               1
       41902000               0
          92599               1
```

Comment: can the number be passed as a string? (especially given the '234543454545444' test case)

Comment: @Uriel You may take input as a string

Comment: As a suggestion for clarification: I would use the term "digit" rather than "number", as you are specifically referring to the decimal characters, abstracted from their number values.

Comment: `list of digits` - would this be a list of the ASCII numeral characters, or a list of integers from 0-9

Comment: @Οurous Up to you

Comment: Would 1 be considered a pleasing number? (01) 0 is 0^1.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk - does not matter since "`x` is guaranteed to have at least two distinct digits" (although I see your "01" reasoning)

Comment: @DLosc Added, Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 36 bytes

```apl
{(⊢≡⌊)(⌈/⍎¨⍵/⍨~o)*÷≢⍵/⍨o←⌽⌊\1,2=/⌽⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqjUddix51LnzU06Wp8ainQ/9Rb9@hFY96twIZK@ryNbUOb3/UuQjKzwdqeNSzF6g2xlDHyFYfxO7dWgs0SeFR71QFE0MLAyMDAwMuCNcQwTIyNjE1M7ewgPJNTA0hAMhXB8mZgDAImpiow/UAAA)

**How?**

*Almost a poem.*

`⌽⍵` - reverse the input once,

`1,2=/` - get the differences list.

`⌊\` - keep only the first group of ones,

`⌽` - and flip it over to complete.

---

`o←` - assign to `o`,

`~o` - switch ones and zero(s),

`⍵/⍨` - filter the input with it,

`⍎¨` - turn the result into list of each digit,

- `⌈/` - and get the maximum. (that's A)

---

`⍵/⍨o` - filter the input with `o` unalt(ered),

`≢` - and take the length, that would be B.

`÷` - get one divided by this result,

`*` - and take A to that power thee.

---

`⊢≡⌊` - integer?

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
γRćgUZXzm.ï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OagI@3poVERVbl6h9f//29iaGFgZGBgAAA)

### Explanation

```
γRćgUZXzm.ï ~ Full program.

γ           ~ Split into runs of digits.
 R          ~ Reverse.
  ć         ~ Push a[1:], a[0] to the stack.
   g        ~ Length (of a[0]).
    U       ~ Assign this to the integer variable X.
     ZX     ~ Get the maximum, without popping, and push X.
       zm   ~ A1/B.
         .ï ~ Is it an integer?
```

[Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna) saved 1 byte.

Relies on the fact that if **A** is a positive integer **N** raised to the power of **B**, then **N=A<sup>1/B</sup>**, hence it  must be an integer.

Comment: `UZX` should work instead of `s{θs`

Comment: The 9-byte program fails for `41902000` (should be falsy).

Comment: @Zgarb Yeah I was nearly sure it would fail, so I removed it... Also [lol](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41802986#41802986) we got the exact same integer

Comment: Fails for `418802000`

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>85</s> <s>75</s> <s>72</s> 71 bytes

***Edit**: -10 bytes by taking a list of digits instead of a string. Thanks to [WhatToDo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76292/whattodo) for pointing out that this is allowed. -3 bytes thanks to [Ourous' solution in Clean](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150964/56433). -1 byte thanks to [user28667](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75762/user28667).*

```hs
f s|(b,a)<-span(==last s)$reverse s=or[n^length b==maximum a|n<-[1..9]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU5RasMwDP3PKfSxjwSUYLtK60B9hJ3AZOCCu4bGXoizMVh39sxZlrJ2y3sIIT09SScTzrZtx/EI4ZIe0GT7PHTGp0q1JgwQsofevtk@WAjqpdf@qbX@eTjBQSln3hv36sBc/D7XvCiquh6daTwocKZ7hLTrGz9AAccMtCbkKJGhiBFZo@bXLHCDhCVucRdnZOxNFf/N2Fum6JqXiJz3fDs5Vnd3pp118pEnMIO4ZIIxBrfgyU21qnOxoXK7k/JOZz86lXzGH30y0hQTiVb8yzmx9h/x6r//WZJ/jl8) Takes input as a list of digits. Example usage: `f [4,1,8,0,2,0,0,0]` yields `True`.

#### Explanation:

Given an input `s=[4,1,8,0,2,0,0,0]`, we `reverse` the list and separate the leading elements with `span(==last s)`: `([0,0,0],[2,0,8,1,4])`.
The pattern matching on `(b,a)` yields `b=[0,0,0]` and `a=[2,0,8,1,4]`.

The list comprehension `or[n^length b==maximum a|n<-[1..a]]` checks whether any integer `n` in the range from `1` to `9` satisfies `n^length b==maximum a`, that is `n^3=8`.

Comment: You posted yours before I did mine, and ours are similar, so: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU3LCsIwELz7FSt4aGEjrdYniTf9Am8hQtRUi20saWpb8N9rqigqw87uDrOzZ1lcVJq2bQz1vaHEqJsyhYIaPYl7n5Iil9pr@v2AMb/BipJM1klWZrBnV8P1zkuVPtkzSJ@x6q4p4cFwWAnRZjLRwCA3ibYwgBjoYAWcRxjiHAMcuXIQyMNPH@EYI5zgFGfOM3dat4XfcNrbFX36uxxeOc/LEBd/f7pM0SME1nWuDlYd4VravLRL4FtTKnzSRqbFL3/J3SjaBw)

Comment: @WhatToDo Thanks, I didn't see that lists of digits where allowed as input.

Comment: Can’t you just take the maximum. No need to check them all.

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Taking the maximum of the whole input list to get `a` would fail in cases like `477`.

Comment: @Tim I do take the maximum to get `b`, but check every integer `n` from `0` to `9` (formerly from `0` to `a`). That's exactly the specification as far as I see.

Comment: I think you can replace `(reverse s)` with `$reverse s`

Comment: @user28667 Thanks, the parenthesis where needed the previous 75 byte version, but now they indeed can be replaced.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>104</s> 89 bytes

@Laikoni found a [shorter solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150960/24877), but this is the best I could do. Thanks @Laikoni for letting me know that we can also accept lists of digits as input.

```
import Data.List
(g.length.last<*>maximum.concat.init).group
g b a=any(==a)$(^b)<$>[1..a]
```

#### Explanation:

[image]

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHNToQwEMfvPMUcOLQGGopdRbP05NE3IJgMaxca@Qp0oz49UlhAV9dpOpl2fvOfaVpg/6bKchh01TadgSc0yJ51b5xjTHJWqjo3BSuxN/sbWeGHrk4VOzT1AQ3TtTaU5V1zap0cMsAY608Sx0hd8pLRvSsTzhimQ4W6hhjaTtcGXDjCmAIgpFP4yshjklqWsr5o3umUSwSPgjAIAo/bHd6K3d19FHlix2fz7JWw2y4hRsYT/GGqSR3fh9kWGfhpfCPm8z/E2vyCCFZiHeoP4mLMqxpL2/D6pMvzfmlYRIEvAa3LrCPKl0iXKKMAIzN@oEXJjJ2zU923eGHdmd10piq1lapzsxGSMqbDFw)

Comment: Why use `any(==a)` when you could use `elem a`?

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks for the suggestions, regarding your second comment: Wouldn' this fail for e.g. `2888`?

Comment: Yes it seems I misread the question.  I didn't realize that the trailing numbers could be anything other than zero.

Comment: but `head.maximum` is still shorter than `maximum.concat` by 2 bytes, and maintains the functionality.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ŒgµṪL9*€fṀL
```

Takes input as a list of digits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPRDWx/uXOVjqfWoaU3aw50NPv@P7nE53A7kqbj//29iaGFgZGBgoKNgCCaMjE1MzcwtLHQUTEwNIUBHASRoAsIgaGICUgaUN7QE6wQA)

#### How it works

```
ŒgµṪL9*€fṀL  Main link. Argument: D (digit array)

Œg           Group runs of digits, yielding a run array R.
  µ          Begin a new chain with argument D.
   Ṫ         Tail; remove and yield the last element of D.
    L        Take the length. Let's call it b.
     9*€     Compute [1**b, ..., 9**b].
         Ṁ   Take the maximum run in R, yileding [a, ..., a].
        f    Filter, yielding either [a] (if a = n**b for some n) or [].
          L  Take the length.
```

Comment: Before looking at the answers, and without knowing Jelly at all, I guessed that the Jelly answer would be 12 bytes. ;)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 80 bytes

```r
function(x)any((0:(m=max((d=rle(rev(utf8ToInt(c(x,''))-48)))$v[-1])))^d$l[1]==m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCoMwEETv/Q7BWaiQ2LWNhXxA772JBVEDBRNBoqRfnzbVXYbZYR67RKOjWV3v37NDoM59AHGH1bYLwKCXacQybli9Uc/54Tx6hHOeExWsiCjbmkK2v@M1ZFMjW60tRQOWSpRCCDoZyMPKC1fXm1IpcCX3SSEVnJSWeYf/lKyPL/EL)

Uses `utf8ToInt - 48` to split the number into digits.  This throws a warning from the conversion to a string.

Using rle get the count of the trailing digits and the max value of the first digits.  Return true if the any of the range 0 to max value to the power of trailing count equals max value.

I think there are further golfing opportunities, but that can wait until tomorrow.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I didn't see that my post was just combining your answer and @NofP's: `function(x,R=rle(rev(utf8ToInt(x)-48)))!max(R$v[-1])^(1/R$l[‌​1])%%1` (66 bytes, taking `x` as a string)

Comment: @plannapus Personally I would undelete it.  It's a better count than both of ours and not really a copy of either

Comment: @plannapus I agree with MickyT!

Comment: @NofP and MickyT: OK then, [here it is](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151013/6741)

Answer (score 5):

## R, 66 bytes

This answer is more or less a medley of [MickyT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150989/6741) and [NofP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150980/6741)'s answers, and on their request, here it is:

```
function(x,R=rle(rev(utf8ToInt(x)-48)))!max(R$v[-1])^(1/R$l[1])%%1
```

It takes x as a string.

```
> f=function(x,R=rle(rev(utf8ToInt(x)-48)))!max(R$v[-1])^(1/R$l[1])%%1
> f("41802000")
[1] TRUE
> f("100")
[1] TRUE
> f("123456788")
[1] FALSE
> f("451111111")
[1] FALSE
> f("234543454545444")
[1] FALSE
> f("12")
[1] TRUE
> f("41902000")
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES7), 66 bytes

Takes input as either a string or an array of characters. Returns a boolean.

```js
f=([c,...s],m)=>s.some(n=>n-c)?f(s,c<m?m:c):!(m**(1/-~s.length)%1)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=([c,...s],m)=>s.some(n=>n-c)?f(s,c<m?m:c):!(m**(1/-~s.length)%1)

console.log(f(       '41802000')) // 1
console.log(f(            '100')) // 1
console.log(f(      '123456788')) // 0
console.log(f(      '451111111')) // 0
console.log(f('234543454545444')) // 0
console.log(f(             '12')) // 1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>130</s> <s>128</s> <s>118</s> 93 bytes

```
import StdEnv
@l#(b,a)=span((==)(last l))(reverse l)
=or[n^length b==last(sort a)\\n<-[0..9]]
```

Defines the function `@`, taking a list of integer digits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDBasMwDIbveQqRXhxo2qRLt3TU0MN2KOyWY5KBG3upwZFDrBb28svsZofZSPow/y8Jd0YJnAcrb0bBIDTOehjtRFCRfMd7dDIrdlmLhLtRIGOcJ8wIR2CShE3qrianPEfcTjV@GoU9XeHCedAwF/qIpGnwmNbZZnNo27kiMVG00jjeyAGHOi7yMttlWRav43zJu6di//xSlp6Lfb4cz@G5CBFuUTyUQZIfFn8bbbfQWfRLEZAFqXvtF9WO3P@BNdkzEjCyFU0ae5AJNA1IOKavoNvA2jMsjkdTuioEaUP14T0R9381wulPNP90X0b0bk7PH/PbN4pBd@4X)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>95</s> 78 bytes

- Saved seventeen bytes thanks to [Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod).

```python
def f(s,i=~0):
	while s[i]==s[~0]:i-=1
	return int(max(s[:-~i]))**(1./~i)%1==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BCoMwDIbP9imKMLAyXdPVzQl9hb2AeBBWsbC10jq2XfrqTpExh0vIJd@f/En36luj2TBcZIObyG2V8JQUKHi06iqxK1UlhCs9rQqVCECBlf3daqx0H93qZ@TKIvGqIiSOI0h3XpENCEGH2jlp@3FjyCGnjFIaEiwEBvQl8LfJ9jw7HPN8RnSBeAZzrNE0xKeakvO1ANjaisNpcdmP@mMPqLPjqzg8GzxjZTSW1hrr0nB4Aw)

Comment: You don't need o sort, you can just get the max, and since you already got `i` you can drop the `len` [reaching 78 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY/BCoMwDIbP@hRFGFiZrunq5oS@wl5APAirWNhaaTu2XXz1TpExh0vIJd@f/En/cp1W1PuLaFEb263kKeAyDB6dvApkK1lzbqsU6lKmHMLACHc3Cknl4lvzjG1VpoOsMU6SGLLdIPEGOCe@sVYYN26MGBSEEkIijDhHEH4J/G3SPcsPx6KYEVkglsMcazQNsammZGwtALq2YnBaXPaj/thD2JvxVRSdNZqx1AoJY7SxWeTf)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>144</s> <s>126</s> 117 bytes

- Saved eighteen bytes thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis).
- Saved nine bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
j,k,m;f(char*N){N+=j=strlen(N);k=~j;for(j=-1;m=N[j--]==N[j];);for(;k++<j;)m=fmax(N[k],m);j=!fmod(pow(m-48,1./~j),1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9RTsMwDIaf4RSl0qSEJpCUDIqMr5ALjD5UKRlL63bqJoE0bUcnLCDxBsWWZVn@/l@2k2vnYgyiEwSeuddmurb8YAsMuNtP/cvALIcOTwH8OLGAUgOhXQUpa0y9Bv61ga4ongJwQk/NO7OrrhbEIeCVp7Fl2/GNkTSV0De3p8CF5nCM1GwGxg@XF9tpM@w9yxdthpgt2uchF@fR6EqVSqmci@ws@JXT/0DKO7O8f6iqBKo/QLPU3zEHJkOTKqUxc7gu5040@vHn2@R0jB/O9816F2VPnw)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 93 bytes

```r
function(x){n=nchar(x)
d=x%/%10^(n:1-1)%%10
i=max(which(d!=d[n]))
max(d[1:i])^(1/(n-i))%%1>0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtNCsIwEIX3uYWLwMyidKZGkEK8SGmhJIRk4SihYkA8e0wW8njw8X5yDbaGl7gjPQQKfsSKi3tuqLwtetRMG8jMA6NurJK97wXeMbkI/mT9Iiui6plfeE4rbsAjyJCw72/0rc@c5IAA09lcTHeXMe31bwxfaSIixPoD)

The code takes an integer as input and returns FALSE if the number is pleasing, and TRUE otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>88</s> 85 bytes

```python
def f(n):p=n.rstrip(n[-1]);a=int(max(p));b=len(n)-len(p);return round(a**(1/b))**b==a
```

#### Ungolfed:

```python
def is_pleasing_number( n ):
    prefix = n.rstrip(n[-1])
    a = int(max(prefix))
    b = len(n) - len(prefix)
    return round(a ** (1 / b)) ** b == a
```

- The input argument is expected to be a digit string
- The output is either `True` or `False`.
- Similar to yet developed independently of [Halvard’s answer](/a/150947/68800) but uses floating point arithmetic in a way that doesn't suffer from rounding errors until `a ** (1 / b)` is off by at least 0.5 from <sup>b</sup>√a which requires a value above 2<sup>53</sup> (or whatever floating point radix and mantissa length Python happens to use, see `sys.float_info`).
- Can be modified trivially to still work with arbitrary number bases between 2 and 36.

Comment: @ovs: With a minor modification, yes. The function would have to take the base as an extra argument and pass it to the invocations of `int` and `range`. (At some point it would become more feasible to estimate the search range based ont `a^(1/b)` than to calculate large amounts of powers.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 106 bytes

```
fun String.p()=split(Regex("(?=(.)\\1*$)")).let{Math.pow((it[0].max()?:'0')-'0'+.0,1.0/(it.size-1))}%1==.0
```

Output: true/false

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU5dr8FAEH3vr2gaYsbHmGVRosQP8MIjHvahaqNW0@7NdYnfXt14cIOZzGRyTuacczzbVJuy3P8Yf21zbRLKAKMiS7WFVZzEFwhgHgHhdiuaNQwQKY3tbansgbLzL4C2G97RSV0A55MGN7BTrRZxWxB3K5YKfY07AvFeF1FE7HnO66S0AZUnxcRf5Ln6mz7NZ@jfvKy6bGogkCLkHjMHLhO@cPEF6vXlYDgKw3dCDsSz3gn3IN24lvJT8ENJjP@nuZflAw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>26</s> 18 bytes

```
ó¶
o l
ñ o n qV v1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///DmQ9u48hVyuA5vVMhXyFMoDFMoM/z/X8nE0MLAyMDAQAkA)

---

Takes input as  a string, returns `1` for pleasing numbers, `0` otherwise.

Short explanation:

```
ó¶
```

Take the first input and split it by values where `(x,y) => x===y` is true. For example `'41802000'` to `['4','1','8','0','2','000']`.

```
o l
```

Take the array from the first step, remove the last element and get its length, yielding **B**.

```
ñ o n qV v1
```

Find the largest element in the remaining array, yielding **A**, take it to the power `1/B` and then return if the result is divisible by one.

---

First time working with Japt, very open to any recommendations.
Shaved off 8 bytes thanks to [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions).

Comment: Hey, welcome to Japt! Sorry I missed your answers at first. A few tips: 1) You can use an [auto-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124037/42545) to turn the first line into just `ó¶`. 2) Not sure why you have the `v` in the second line, as it just converts the string to lowercase and has no effect on the length ;-) 3) You can avoid the `!(U` on the last line by changing `%1` to `v1`, which returns `1` if the subject is divisible by 1 or `0` otherwise.

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks a lot for your feedback, really appreciate it. I read about auto-functions before, but I still haven't quite gotten the hang of it, thanks for the example. I've incorporated the rest of your changes too, adding up to a total of 8 bytes lost.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 64 bytes

```ruby
->a{!([a[/(\d)\1*$/].size,$`.chars.max]*?x!~/x1$|^2x[49]|^3x8/)}
```

Input as a string, returns true if:

- B==1 (no need to check A)
- A==4 and B==2
- A==9 and B==2
- A==8 and B==3

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxLDoIwFACvItgFkNofRetCPUh5xPohujAhEJOnbb16xTiZ2c74PL1Sv0urvfNZYZ3lRXspW1kRDmy6v6@UHNn55saJPRxCdcDsw1GS0Cm0eguhq9HwMiarpRFKCEHlLzVb62a9MYbqRv6B@TH4gGFYWKS9zZceYw4Q0xc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 55 bytes

```
{m/(\d+?)((\d)$0*)$/;so any(^10)**$1.comb==$0.comb.max}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JUtbDoIwELzKhjSmrQns4oIoohcxmvrolxUDPzaEs9cWZzKPbHY@z@FVB@dhZaELkyvk@bE@KRlDCdRKFO3Yg3l7eSFUWgvK7727dZ3ApeTOfOfQwmg8ZJMFcZ330TKw/QAHpgZLRARKKjdc1dumAa7oD0gnTkpkjj/AtFs2xzb8AA)

After the evaluation of the initial regex--which can only succeed if the input is a positive integer--`$0` contains the initial part of the number, and `$1` contains the trailing repeated digits.

The `comb` method without arguments, applied to a string, returns a list of the characters, which in numeric context evaluates to the length of the list.  So `$0.comb.max` is the largest of the digits in the prefix, and `$1.comb` is the length of the suffix.

We then check whether `any(^10)` (ie, the or-junction of the numbers from 0-9), when raised to the power of the length of the suffix, is equal to the largest digit in the prefix.  The `so` forces boolean evaluation of the resulting junction, which would otherwise be just fine on its own as a truthy value, but the challenge calls for just two distinct values to be returned.

Comment: This is late, but since the input is guaranteed to be an integer, the regex can use `.` instead of `\d`.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 132 bytes

```cs
n=>{int A=0,B=1,s=1,i=n.Length-1;for(;i-->0;)if(n[i]==n[i+1]&s>0)B++;else{A=n[i]>A?n[i]:A;s=0;}return System.Math.Pow(A,1d/B)%1==0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZBBS8QwEIXP9lfkojR0Wpu16mpMpRU87ULBg4fSQ@1mdwM1gSZ1kdLfXlOxIp5aHm8GMvOYj1Tar1TDh1YLeUAvn9rwd@pUdak1yjpHm9KICj23snoQ0uQFoDel6hhlNS@/IwwNksWdHaKEhZAyAtpaMBlsuDyYo0/oXjUuFb4fhxSLvStzUTBmq0eKCx2HOPU8ymvNu2R8LeLkcWz3CdUspH3DTdvIH7ZgW5pjkKmTmwDZXab4nLBxaaDOBPuhxA5tSyFd7HTO2ZOSWtU8eG2E4RshuTuxu5Kf8gJ1KAICawhhZW2FeozprCBZur6CK4jgGm7g1l5cz4@OIfJX86PTzei3T7ZaBL8El8Dd/x/tnX74Ag)

#### Acknowledgements

-12 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen

#### DeGolfed

```cs
n=>{
    int A=0, // maximum digit
        B=1, // count of trailing identical numbers
        s=1, // 1 if dealing with trailing numbers, 0 otherwise
        i=n.Length-1;

    for(; i-- > 0;)
        if(n[i] == n[i+1] & s > 0)
            B++;
        else
        {
            A = n[i] > A? n[i] : A;
            s = 0;
        }

    return Math.Pow(A, 1d/B) % 1 == 0;
}
```

Comment: I know it's been a while, but `i=n.Length-2;for(;i>=0;i--)` can be golfed to `i=n.Length-1;for(;i-->0;)` and `&&` can be golfed to `&`.

Comment: Oh, and you can golf 6 more bytes by removing the `using System;` and using `System.Math.Pow` directly.

Comment: One last thing. You currently take a list of characters, but it's also allowed to take a list of digits. In which case the `-48` can be golfed for -3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 21 bytes

```
L,BGubLV@¦+bMG1$/^1%!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hx8m9NMknzOHQMu0kX3dDFf04Q1XF/yo5iblJKYkKhnb2XP5cRPP@/482UTBUsFAwUDACYiCM/R9tpGCsYKJgCsQwGoaBEChvqGAUC9JnCtSJBGMB)

It's been 3 and a half months, I hope I'm not ninja'ing anyone.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 168 bytes

```
(fn[x](let[y(reverse(vec x))z(count(take-while #(= %(first y))y))a(apply max(map #(-(int %)48)(drop z y)))b(Math/pow a(/ 1 z))](<(Math/abs(- b(Math/round b)))0.00001)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VRRbsIwDP3fKSwQ0vNHoWFhFAmOsBMgPtISRFloozQtbS/fpWI7RJ5jyYmeEz/FcmHqR@v0NMG6svKmIuBWnfsLjPbnAU532jUanS6oZx5R1G3l4dWPTl730mha4kQr3ErXeBqYw1JQ1pqBnqrHU9nASBDuphXLjHF1taVxpnKOb@XvG1u/SGFDgkbmC47vU5U3SOiP4sKrV8pDTrpOA0SIaCFFlm7DbsH8EWP9IuLSt59y97XPslgFyJ14I1YB8wfI2WeTMt5GiraDxOF/@kzTLw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
≔ＥＳιθ⊞υ⊟θＷ⁼§υ⁰§θ±¹⊞υ⊟θ¬﹪ＸＩ⌈θ∕¹Ｌυ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY2xCsMgEIb3PoXjCRZM6VDIFNoOgSYIfQJpJBGMxqhJ3t6eQ6ce3HAf/33/Z5Lrx0mTcxOCHi10coHWLim@46rtCJQRjetpfRIpTJAYEW4BTxHskzaKwNMnaQI0sbWDOkqC48fv9Iz0apRRQUVxyJ9FYE@E3kXo3JCMA@F2tcJdBiTy0HOaS5CRh970gBpGXsqOES204KKtc75WN37hnOfzZr4) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a `-` for pleasing numbers. Explanation:

```
≔ＥＳιθ
```

Split the input `q` into characters.

```
⊞υ⊟θ
```

Remove the last character from `q` and push it to `u` (predefined to an empty list).

```
Ｗ⁼§υ⁰§θ±¹⊞υ⊟θ
```

Repeatly pop and push while the last character of `q` is the first character of `u`.

```
¬﹪ＸＩ⌈θ∕¹Ｌυ¹
```

Take the maximum digit of `q` and raise it to the power of the reciprocal of the length of `u`, then check whether the result is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>91</s> 85 bytes

```python
s=`input()`;d=0
p=s.rstrip(s[-1])
exec"`d**(len(s)-len(p))`==max(p)>exit(1);d+=1;"*10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcbBCsIwDADQ@z5jp6QySYaHQYk/IkJlLazgalgq1K@venpPP3V7lbl3k5CLvitg8FFoULHzYfXICnab@I5DamkdQ3QOnqmA4fRHEYPI/mi/XVPLFRh9PAn70TH1fuGFZiL6Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 73 + 1 (`-p`) = 74 bytes

```perl
s/(.)\1*$//;$/=length$&;$_=(sort/./g)[-1];$q=$"++**$/while$q<$a;$_=$q==$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpNCoUgFAbQvTw@Hv2gVweNzCW0gopoIBVIWgrtvluNz4nu9A1zokKWg65AZEDWu33JK/4Gky1SODNJWspe6NHgsPjVdfXWa928w9Fi/t4LFjOzVuoOMW9hTyy6RiqtWMQH)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 125 bytes

```java
a->{int A=0,B=1,f=1,i=a.length-1;for(;i-->0;)if(a[i]==a[i+1]&f>0)B++;else{A=a[i]>A?a[i]:A;f=0;}return Math.pow(A,1d/B)%1==0;}
```

Port of [*@Ayb4btu*'s C# .NET answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152068/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lVDBbsIwDL33K3zZlAq3axjb2KJ0Kvdx4Yh6CCWFsJKiNoCmqt/euTCmSbuArGcrtp/8XjbqoILN8rPLClXX8KGMbTwAY52ucpVpmPZPgEVZFlpZyBiN5ikoX1C/9SjVTjmTwRQsSOhUEDe0AomMcCI55gQjVVhou3LrgIu8rJgwQRBHwjc5U3OTSkl5wNP7PI78yWAgdFHrJum7aZy89@UtEbmMRFtpt68s6XTrcFceWYJ8@TDx77jsp53oBe32i4IE/eg6lGYJW/LFZq4ydjVPlX/2NPuqnd6G5d6FO5q4wjIbZszqI5xMNiPkOMYIhwSK1j@ZvoLIb10f4iOO8Amf8YUujq@n9iT@N66nXm6OfusFFDeJv0Uux9d/P9p6bfcN)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->{                       // Method with digit-array parameter and boolean return-type
  int A=0,                 //  Maximum digit `A` as specified in the challenge description
      B=1,                 //  `B` as specified in the challenge description
      f=1,                 //  Flag-integer, starting at 1
      i=a.length-1;        //  Index integer `i`
  for(;i-->0;)             //  Loop `i` backwards over the digits (excluding the last)
    if(a[i]==a[i+1]        //   If the current and next digits are the same,
       &f>0)               //   and the flag is still 1
      B++;                 //    Increase `B` by 1
    else{                  //   Else:
      A=a[i]>A?            //    If the current digit is larger than `A` 
         a[i]              //     Replace `A` with the current digit
        :                  //    Else:
         A;                //     Leave `A` the same
      f=0;}                //    Set the flag-integer to 0
  return Math.pow(A,1d/B)  //  Return if `A` ^ (1/`B`)
    %1==0;}                //  is an exact integer
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>32</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
'.N(#a-#Ya<|a@v)RTMXy
```

Uses `1` for *falsey* and `0` for *truthy*, saving a byte. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fXc9PQzlRVzky0aYm0aFMMyjEN6Ly////JoYWBkYGBgYA)

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 29 bytes

```
JezWqezJ=Pz=hZ)K@sh.MsZzZqKsK
```

[**Test suite**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JezWqezJ%3DPz%3DhZ%29K%40sh.MsZzZqKsK&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=41802000%0A100%0A123456788%0A451111111%0A234543454545444%0A12%0A41902000&debug=0)

Python 3 translation:

```
Z=0
z=input()
J=z[-1]
while z[-1]==J:
    z=z[:-1]
    Z+=1
K=max(map(int,z))**(1/Z)
print(K==int(K))
```