# Is it a Satisfying Number?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, integer

<sup>inspired by [this chat conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/conversation/satisfying-numbers)</sup>

A *satisfying number* is a number whose decimal representation is of the form `abx`, with the following properties:

- `x` is the longest trailing repeating suffix, or the last digit if there is no repetition at the end (`123333` -> `3333`, `545656` -> `5656`, `123` -> `3`)
- `b` is the single digit prior to `x` (`123333` -> `2`, `55545656` -> `4`)
- `a` is the remaining prefix (`123333` -> `1`, `55545656` -> `555`)
- `a == c**b` (`**` denotes exponentation), where `c` is the number of repetitions of the smallest repeating portion of `x` (`1623333` -> `4` (`3 3 3 3`, not `33 33`))

For example, `8300` is a satisfying number with `a = 8`, `b = 3`, `c = 2`, and `x = 00`. `24651` is not a satisfying number, because `x = 1`, `b = 5`, `a = 246`, and there is no integer `c` that satisfies `c^5 = 246`. `1222` is also not a satisfying number, because with `x = 222` and `b = 1`, there are no remaining digits for `a`.

Given a positive integer `n >= 100`, output whether or not `n` is a satisfying number.

### Examples

```
8300: True (a=8, b=3, c=2, x=00)
24651: False 
1222: False
92555: True (a=9, b=2, c=3, x=555)
64633: True (a=64, b=6, c=2, x=33)
512944: True (a=512, b=9, c=2, x=44)
123: True (a=1, b=2, c=1, x=3)
822809: False 
376664: False 
723799: False 
1234: False 
34330000000: True (a=343, b=3, c=7, x=0000000)
92313131: True (a=9, b=2, c=3, x=313131)
16424442444: True (a=16, b=4, c=2, x=24442444)
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14419/45941)

Comment: Also somewhat [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150936/is-it-a-pleasing-number).

Comment: With `8333` is `x,c,b,a=33,2,3,8` and therefore satisfying?

Comment: @JonathanAllan No, because `x` is greedy.

Comment: OK, thanks, so `a` is undefined here? (hence not satisfactory?)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Exactly. A number having at least two digits before a repeating portion is a necessary condition for being satisfying.

Comment: Huh. I’d thought a number like 477223 is satisfying.

Comment: Must the number of repetitions be chosen as large as possible? For example, in `1645555`, can we choose `55` as the repeated string so that `x = 55 55` and  `c = 2`?

Comment: Another test case: `16424442444`.

Comment: @Zgarb "`x` is the **longest** trailing repeating suffix" - as explained in a previous comment, `x` is greedy.

Comment: @Mego But what about **c**? If **x = 5555**, **c** could be **2** (two repetitions of **55**) or **4** (four repetitions of **5**).

Comment: @Dennis I see the confusion now. I'll clarify.

Comment: Does longest repeating suffix refer to longest in terms of what is repeated, the number of times it is repeated, the length of all of the repetitions, or does it not matter? So is the longest repeating suffix of `133333` equal to `3 3 3 3 3` or `33 33`?

Comment: @Dopapp Longest repeating suffix means the longest string at the end of the original string that has repetition. The grouping does not matter for the purpose of determining the longest repeating suffix.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 26 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>feels too long</sup>

```
DŒṖṖEÐƤḄ$ÐṀLÐṂṪµḢ*@0¦LµṪ⁼Ḍ
```

A monadic link taking an integer and returning `1` if the input is satisfying and `0` if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l6KSHO6cBkevhCceWPNzRonJ4wsOdDT4gsunhzlWHtj7csUjLweDQMh8gc@eqR417Hu7o@f//v6WRsSEIAgA)** or see a [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l6KSHO6cBkevhCceWPNzRonJ4wsOdDT4gsunhzlWHtj7csUjLweDQMh8gc@eqR417Hu7o@X90z@H2R01r3P//j7YwNjDQsTQyNTXVMTMxMzbWMTU0sjQx0TE0MtYxNjEGyoIBUImxIQjqGJmYmRoCpY2MdCyMjCwMLHWMzc3MzEx0zI2MzS0tQRpNYgE)

#### How?

```
DŒṖṖEÐƤḄ$ÐṀLÐṂṪµḢ*@0¦LµṪ⁼Ḍ - Link: integer, n    e.g. 8300
D                          - to decimal list          [8,3,0,0]
 ŒṖ                        - all partitions           [[[8],[3],[0],[0]],[[8],[3],[0,0]],[[8],[3,0],[0]],[[8],[3,0,0]],[[8,3],[0],[0]],[[8,3],[0,0]],[[8,3,0],[0]],[[8,3,0,0]]]
   Ṗ                       - pop (the "no tail" one)  [[[8],[3],[0],[0]],[[8],[3],[0,0]],[[8],[3,0],[0]],[[8],[3,0,0]],[[8,3],[0],[0]],[[8,3],[0,0]],[[8,3,0],[0]]]
         ÐṀ                - keep maximal under the operation: e.g. for [[8,3],[0],[0]]
        $                  -   last two links as a monad:
     ÐƤ                    -     for suffixes:   i.e. [[[8,3],[0],[0]],[[0],[0]],[[0]]]
    E                      -       all equal?         [0              ,1        ,1]
       Ḅ                   -     convert from binary  3
                           -          ...which yields [[[8],[3],[0],[0]],[[8,3],[0],[0]]]
            ÐṂ             - keep minimal under the operation:
           L               -   length
                           -          ...which yields [[[8,3],[0],[0]]]
              Ṫ            - tail (rightmost)         [[8,3],[0],[0]] 
               µ           - monadic chain separation
                Ḣ          - yield head and modify    [8,3]   ...leaving [[0],[0]]
                     L     - length (of modified)     2
                    ¦      - sparse application       (to the [8,3])
                   0       -   ...to index: 0         (to the rightmost digit, the 3)
                 *@        -   power (sw@p args)      [8,8]  ([8, 3*@2] = [8, 2*3] = [8,8])
                      µ    - monadic chain separation
                       Ṫ   - yield tail and modify    8   ...leaving [8]
                         Ḍ - from decimal (modified)  8
                        ⁼  - equal?                   1
```

Comment: Don't worry, you're not alone. [This](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hztn6Ryc93DkNiFy5jB7u7vZ5uLvrxHKfR417jFVUTiw/3M7lAlZwuP3whLSHOxYd2vpw5yofLSDxcEePClAZUAzE@v//v6WRsSEIAgA) piece of unfinished torture should prove my point.

Comment: If the Jelly answer is >20 bytes, you know somethings wrong...

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 141 bytes

```python
a=b=0;k=[]
c=[*input()];l=len(c)
while c[1:]>[]==k:a=a*10+b;b=int(c.pop(0));k=[i for i in range(2,l)if c==i*c[:l//i]];l-=1
a==(k+[1])[0]**b>q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU67csIwEOz1FRoabJME62GDzRwdKZMmnUaFrMigsSM7Qkzg6x2LSUGRu@Lmbvd2d7yF0@DYpIdPA4vFYlLQQL7rQEikQWTWjZeQpHLXQ29colP0c7K9wVqQWu6FBOhqBSoj@arZNWBdSPTLOIxJnqZRxeJ28Nhi67BX7mgS@tSntsUawGZa1P16beWs/gwEKYCkWwkiU5HLLGv239Oc6M/ww19MjTAO/hYHxuZqdBJjp/d19NF76YaAzyrYc3uz7riMmLlqMwb8pr7MwfvB14/8/7mH99cHauON6qYty3NEeVkQRCilqKJFUaCSl4yhgtCK8/nO0JbSbV4htinLkqMNZZuqigBHjLNZ4l7zMyOxfwE)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 144 bytes

```python
a=b='';k=[]
c=[*input()];l=len(c)
while c[1:]>[]==k:a+=b;b,*c=c;k=[i for i in range(2,l)if c==i*c[:l//i]];l-=1
int(a or-1)==(k+[1])[0]**int(b)>q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU47b8IwEN79KyyWxAFE/EggQcdGx3bpFnlwXANWUic1RoVfn8aoQ4feDae773Hf@AiXwfFJDx8GFovFpKCFJNl30EikocmsG28hJXLfQ29cqgn6vtjeYN3QWh4aCdDVagntvl1lGnQUWnwaPLbYOuyVO5uUrXpiT1gD2Ew3db/ZWDkbroEi60Kq8ODXlACk3bKhkjS5zLIItOTwNc2hfl@@@5upEcbBP@LA2NyNTmNy8lxHH0WJGwK@qmCvp4d15yRi5q7NGPCr@jRH7wdf/@X/zz2@vfyhtt6obtrxPEdMlAVFlDGGKlYUBSpFyTkqKKuEmO8c7Rjb5RXi27IsBdoyvq2qCAjEBZ8tnjWLOY39Aw)

output is via exit code

Comment: You can alter your `while` condition to save a byte: [TIO](https://tio.run/##bU4xUsMwEOz1Ck2aSA4QS7Kd2OHoQgkNncaFLOREYyMbRRmS1xsrNCm4K27udm93x2s4Dk5Mevg0sFgsJgUNpLsOZI00yMS68RwIrXc99MYRTdHP0fZG1gDds5asqisFKmHpqtk1YF0g@mkcRpJSGkUsbgePLbYOe@UOhvCHntoWawCbaFn167WtZ/FHYEgBkG4lWU1lWidJ8/I9zYH@/PCHP5sKYRz8NQ6MzcVoElPT2zr66L10Q8AnFeypvVp3WEbMXLQZA35TX2bv/eCre/7/3P376x218UZ101akKeJZkTPEOOeo5HmeoyIrhEA542WWzXeBtpxv0xKJTVEUGdpwsSnLCGRIZGKWuNX8LFjsXw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 66 bytes

```
{/^(\d+?)(\d)((\d+?)$0+||\d)$/&&($2.comb/($2[0]||1).comb)**$1==$0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzbCoMwEER/ZZAgXqAmu0k0tNoP6UV686lisU@ifruNdhaGObvsfF792y7tgLBBuYzZNTo/02PsPY7@Uch0mjyKLAwjQbtH194zH07yMk0q3jhOEqHKUsh52eN7GxCIGmWFsYGo5wBN1@NQsJQgbY2CIiI4MsbAassMo8hp7feMgqiQDpxbazVy4ty59aDBmn3FJv/Map1q@QE)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>282</s> 268 bytes

```js
t=(d,n,l,i,r)=>d.slice((m=-l*i)-l,m).join``!=n?r:t(d,n,l,i+1,{p:r.p+n,r:r.r+1});p=(d,l,r)=>l<1?r:p(d,l-1,r.r<(z=t(d,(m=d.slice(-l).join``),l,1,{p:m,r:1})).r&&(z.r>1|l==1)?z:r);u=n=>(d=[...n]).slice(0,(q=(s=d.length)-(m=p(d,s,{p:"",r:0})).p.length-1)).join``==m.r**d[q]

function onChange() {
  var value = document.getElementById("input").value;
  console.log("%s => %s", value, u(value));
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" onchange="onChange()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 101 bytes

```
import re
x,_,b,a=re.findall(r"((.+?)\2+)(.)(.*)",input()[::-1])[0]
if int(a[::-1])!=len(x)**int(b):d
```

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 107 bytes

```
import re
x,_,b,a=re.findall(r"((.+?)\2+)(.)(.*)",input()[::-1])[0]
if int(a[::-1])!=len(x)**int(b):int('')
```

Output is by exit code.

This code doesn't run properly on Tio due to a range error. Works perfectly in IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 286 bytes

*<sub>yeesh.</sub>*

```
n=`input()`
N=lambda p,l=0:N(n[:-len(p)],p,l+1)if n[-len(p):]==p else l
try:
    s=[(N(n[-i-1:]),n[-i-1:])for i,_ in enumerate(n)if N(n[-i-1:])!=1]
    if len(s)==0:s=[(1,n[-1])]
    q=max(s,key=lambda a:len(a[0]*a[1]))
    i=len(q[0]*q[1])
    print n[:-i-1]==`min(s)[0]**int(n[-i-1])`
except:print 0
```

`N` is a recursive function that finds the number of times a suffix substring is repeated in a string. This basically loops through all possible suffixes, finding the number of times each is repeated using `N`; this excludes all values where `N==1` because they refer to no repeats; if the list ends up being empty, the suffix of the last character is appended to the list.

Then, the longest suffix is taken, (`q`), the number of characters it takes up is found (`i`), and `a==c**b` is checked (`print ...`).

If an error occurs along the way (which it often will), it is caught in the `except` block.

Any suggestions are more than welcome!